# How Can I get parameter's value in Object class?

Tags: java, spring, object, testing

```java
 public void findAllByMenuId() {
        //given
        boardRepository.save(FREE_BOARD);
        boardRepository.save(NOTICE_BOARD);
        boardRepository.save(NOTICE_BOARD_2);
        Integer freeBoardId = FREE_BOARD.getMenu().getId();
        Integer noticeBoardId = NOTICE_BOARD.getMenu().getId();

        //when
        Page<Object> freeBoards = boardRepository.findAllByMenuId(freeBoardId, Pageable.ofSize(5));
        Page<Object> noticeBoards = boardRepository.findAllByMenuId(noticeBoardId, Pageable.ofSize(5));

        //then
        assertThat(freeBoards.getTotalElements()).isEqualTo(1);
        freeBoards.forEach(
                board->assertThat(board.getMenuId()).isEqualTo(freeBoardId)); // error in getMenuId()

        assertThat(noticeBoards.getTotalElements()).isEqualTo(2);
        noticeBoards.forEach(
                board->assertThat(board.getMenuId()).isEqualTo(noticeBoardId)); // error in getMenuId()
    }
```

hi. I wanna know how can I get MenuId in Object class.

In the service logic, it was not possible to use the separately designed Dto, but an object was created using the Object class. As a side effect during the test process, there was a problem that the menuId defined inside could not be obtained.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your `findAllByMenuId` defines what it returns, so check that. Judging by this code that would probably be a `Board` or rather a `Page<Board>`.

Comment: ```findAllByMenuId``` is Test function, so It doesn't return anything

Comment: I doubt that `boardRepository.findAllByMenuId` isn't returning anything... Else your code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: I understand. But ```boardRepository.findAllbyMenuId``` returns something that is ```Page<Object>``` type.

Comment: I just know how to get 'menuId' in Object class. 

Comment: I doubt it returns `Page<Object>` The `BoardRepository` (assuming Spring Data) is mapped to a type. The `findAllByMenuId` needs to reflect this. Without knowing the type it is simply impossible to get what you need. You simply cannot get something from `Object`. Because your `menuId` might be an element in an array, a collection, a map or a property of an specific object. So without knowing the exact return type of that repository method (or that method is just flawed!) it will be impossible to answer.